# Python Twitter Bot for Lyrics - lyrics collected using lyricsgenius package

Tags: python, string

I am using the lyricsgenius python package (https://pypi.org/project/lyricsgenius/) to make a Twitter Lyrics bot as per this tutorial - https://medium.com/@mahibhosain98/creating-a-lyrics-bot-on-twitter-with-python3-and-aws-lambda-1e22743dc3b7

So far my app successfully returns the lyrics for a randomly selected song by the specified artist using the following code:

```
all_songs = ["array_of_song_titles"]

def get_raw_lyrics():
    genius_client_access_token = "my_access_token"
    genius = lyricsgenius.Genius(genius_client_access_token)
    random_song_title = random.choice(all_songs)
    lyrics = genius.search_song(random_song_title, "Artist Name").lyrics
    song = random_song_title.upper()
    return lyrics, song

lyrics, song = get_raw_lyrics()

print(lyrics)
```

However, when I print the lyrics, I can see that after the final lyric it also picks up 'EmbedShare URLCopyEmbedCopy' from genius.com.

For example the final line would look like

```
'Dancing to electro-pop like a robot from 1984
Said, from 1984EmbedShare URLCopyEmbedCopy'
```

How do I prevent EmbedShare URLCopyEmbedCopy from appearing in the final lyric string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `print(lyrics.replace("EmbedShare URLCopyEmbedCopy", ""))` work for your use case?

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix is to not print them with string indexing

```
print(lyrics[:-27])
```

Since the length of the string is 27, so we don't want the last 27 characters