# lyricsgenius lyrics sometimes end with "EmbedShare URLCopyEmbedCopy"

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, genius-api

I am making a Discord lyrics bot and to receive the lyrics. I am using genius API (`lyricsgenius` API wrapper). But when I receive the lyrics, it ends with this:

[image]

"away" is the last word in the song but it is accompanied with `EmbedShare URLCopyEmbedCopy`. Sometimes it is just the plain lyrics without the `EmbedShare` text.

With the same song:

[image]

Is there anyway to prevent that?

Source code for the `lyrics` command:

```
@commands.command(help="Gives the lyrics of the song XD! format //lyrics (author) (song name)")
async def lyrics(self, ctx, arg1, arg2):
    song = genius.search_song(arg1, arg2)
    print(song.lyrics)
    name = ("Lyrics for " + arg2.capitalize() + " by " + arg1.capitalize())
    gembed = discord.Embed(title=name.capitalize(), description=song.lyrics)
    await ctx.send(embed=gembed)
```

Comment: Maybe you can try removing the unwanted string from your lyrics text, as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68512481/1089912 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug with `lyricsgenius` and there's an open PR to address this issue: https://github.com/johnwmillr/LyricsGenius/pull/215.

This is because `lyricsgenius` web **scrapes** the lyrics from Genius' website, which means if their website updates, `lyricsgenius` would fail to fetch the lyrics. This library hasn't been updated in 6 months; itself being a web **scraping** library means that kind of inactivity would render the library severely unstable. Since the library is licensed under MIT, you can fork the library and maintain an up-to-date version for your project/bot. However, it would be much better to use a dedicated API to fetch songs lyrics to guarantee stability.

Also, `lyricsgenius` uses the synchronous `requests` library, which means it'll "block" your asynchronous bot while it fetches the lyrics. This is definitely undesirable for a Discord Bot since your bot would be completely unresponsive while it fetches the lyrics. Consider rewriting it using `aiohttp` or use [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) when calling blocking functions.

Comment: Thank you for helping me and I appreciate that you took a bit of your time to explain this to me! again thank you soo much!

Comment: @Diamondifier Welcome to stack overflow! No worries, glad I was able to help :) Since you're new here, I'd like to remind you that if this or any answer has solved your questions, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark next to the answer. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. You don't need to feel obligated to do this though.

Answer (score 0):

[Some Random API](https://some-random-api.ml/docs/examples/Python) is something easy to deal with when you are creating a command that will send you the song lyrics.

This is how to do it with some random api,

```
# these imports are used for this particular lyrics command. the essential import here is aiohttp, which will be used to fetch the lyrics from the API
import textwrap
import urllib
import aiohttp
import datetime

@bot.command(aliases = ['l', 'lyrc', 'lyric']) # adding aliases to the command so they they can be triggered with other names
async def lyrics(ctx, *, search = None):
    """A command to find lyrics easily!"""
    if not search: # if user hasnt given an argument, throw a error and come out of the command
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title = "No search argument!",
            description = "You havent entered anything, so i couldnt find lyrics!"
        )
        return await ctx.reply(embed = embed)
        # ctx.reply is available only on discord.py version 1.6.0, if you have a version lower than that use ctx.send
    
    song = urllib.parse.quote(search) # url-encode the song provided so it can be passed on to the API
    
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as lyricsSession:
        async with lyricsSession.get(f'https://some-random-api.ml/lyrics?title={song}') as jsondata: # define jsondata and fetch from API
            if not 300 > jsondata.status >= 200: # if an unexpected HTTP status code is recieved from the website, throw an error and come out of the command
                return await ctx.send(f'Recieved poor status code of {jsondata.status}')

            lyricsData = await jsondata.json() # load the json data into its json form

    error = lyricsData.get('error')
    if error: # checking if there is an error recieved by the API, and if there is then throwing an error message and returning out of the command
        return await ctx.send(f'Recieved unexpected error: {error}')

    songLyrics = lyricsData['lyrics'] # the lyrics
    songArtist = lyricsData['author'] # the author's name
    songTitle = lyricsData['title'] # the song's title
    songThumbnail = lyricsData['thumbnail']['genius'] # the song's picture/thumbnail

    # sometimes the song's lyrics can be above 4096 characters, and if it is then we will not be able to send it in one single message on Discord due to the character limit
    # this is why we split the song into chunks of 4096 characters and send each part individually
    for chunk in textwrap.wrap(songLyrics, 4096, replace_whitespace = False):
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title = songTitle,
            description = chunk,
            color = discord.Color.blurple(),
            timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        )
        embed.set_thumbnail(url = songThumbnail)
        await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

Comment: Hi! I sincerely thank you for helping me here! This is really appreciated!